# Nine inch Nail's Satellite is inspired by which Prince's song?

Tags: prince

A long time ago I've heard a Prince song that supposedly inspired Trent Reznor to create Nine Inch Nail's Satellite, but I can't remember its name.

Comment: I've flagged to close this question, because there really is no way to answer this. I assumed you read an interview with Reznor where he discusses this topic, but as you've stated in the comments to my answer: "But I'm sure that there is song from Prince which resembles Reznor's Satellite." And that is quite frankly an unanswerable question.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open, only because if someone can dig up that interview then a definitive answer is possible.

Comment: BTW, here's an interesting little chat about cross-influences which apparently ended after Reznor met Prince and was completely turned off by his personality: http://prince.org/msg/7/319359

Comment: @JohnnyBones Such an interview doesn't exist, and the user's answer -- "The song that Satellite is to some extent reminiscent of is Prince's song Kiss." -- is a personal opinion which is based on nothing substantial.

Answer (score 3):

NIN songs are well-documented on the NinWiki, and [Satellite's entry](http://www.nin.wiki/Satellite) has no mention of it being inspired by a specific Prince song.

You've probably misremembered a review, e.g. [this one from The Quietus](http://thequietus.com/articles/13230-nine-inch-nails-hesitation-marks-review):

> Even more of a core point about those moments of vocals and rhythm in
>   perfect sync: it's Prince. No matter how torn up and explosive, he's
>   also wanted to be Prince at his most futuristic and spare, if maybe
>   with a little extra echo and bass - check the credits for Pretty Hate
>   Machine for an early shout-out - and he's been able to pull it off a
>   lot more than some to transform it into his own thing.  It's why
>   'Closer' worked so well, then and now (not to mention the still
>   underrated 'Into The Void' from The Fragile) while **on this album, it's
>   why 'Satellite' rumbles and clicks like the Neptunes at THEIR most
>   stripped down and Prince-obsessed.**

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't a direct inspiration. But I'm sure that there is song from Prince which resembles Reznor's Satellite. Just like A Warm Place is inspired by Crystal Japan from Bowie, but much more subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube user answered my question under one of the Satellite uploads on YT. The song that Satellite is to some extent reminiscent of is Prince's song Kiss. Especially the guitar/synth riff playing in the background.

Answer (score 1):

For me, sounds pretty similar to: Prince - U Got The Look